# Is this simple symmetric matrix positive semi-definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

Let the $n\times n$ symmetric matrix $A$, where $n\geq 9$ be given by
\begin{equation}
A_{i,j}=
\begin{cases}
1.4, &\text{for } 1\leq i=j\leq 9\\
(0.9)^{|i-j|},&\text{for } 1\leq i\neq j\leq 9\\
0, &\text{else } 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Is this matrix positive semi-definite? it look similar to the covariance matrix of the AR(1) process. So I guess yes.

Comment: Which "else" ??

Comment: Is it now clear?

Comment: Ok, so mostly zeroes.

Comment: So the top 9by9 block is non-zero, the rest zero? Since this top-block is positive definite numerically, the matrix augmented by zero rows and columns is positive definite as well.